# Save streamed video from KinesisVideoStream using boto3 to a local file

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

So I have a stream going on in KVS.
I am trying to save it (in chunks of 1 min for example)
However, when saving the `botocore.response.StreamingBody`, I am getting only 1 sec video.

Here is the code I am using:

```
 client = boto3.client('kinesis-video-media', endpoint_url=url)
 response = client.get_media(
            StreamARN=MyARN,
            StartSelector={
            'StartSelectorType': 'EARLIEST',
            })
 with open('test.webm', 'w+') as f:
     chunk = response['Payload'].read(1024*8)
     while chunk:
         f.write(chunk)
         chunk = response['Payload'].read(1024*8)
```

How can I make it 1 minute video files?

Thank you!