# Convert .webm file to jpg with python

Tags: python, amazon-kinesis

Is there a way to programmatically convert from .webm bytes to a jpg file format with python? Specifically I am getting a stream of .webm bytes from Amazon Kinesis Video and I would like to sample that stream of bytes to produce a jpg every x seconds.

UPDATE to include code:

```
stream = video_client.get_media(StreamARN=myARN,StartSelector={'StartSelectorType': 'NOW'})
chunk = stream['Payload'].read(1024 * 8)
with open('test.webm', 'wb+') as f:
    while chunk:
         f.write(chunk)
         chunk = stream['Payload'].read(1024 * 8)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test.webm')
ret, frame = cap.read()
```

I adapted my code from this question [Save streamed video from KinesisVideoStream using boto3 to a local file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53516866/save-streamed-video-from-kinesisvideostream-using-boto3-to-a-local-file). Using cv2 I am able to convert the entire file to jpg's but I would like to be able to just convert they bytes from memory without having to create a file, stop the stream, and then read the file.

Comment: Have you tried any code so far? Would pls you share what have you tried in your question?

Comment: Yes I just added my current code, sorry about that.

Comment: @Mucully Can you please tell why read(1024 * 8).
should we change according to the source or its the default one